# SQL Server instance list in ODBC not populating

Tags: sql-server, odbc, dsn, sql-server-native-client

I have two computers connected to the same switch on the same network with the same subnet, and when I go to either 32 or 64-bit ODBC to create a System DSN and attempt to add a new DSN using the **SQL Server Native Client 11.0**, the Server list is empty on one but fully populated on the other. I have a local SQL Server on both computers.

[image]

*The last two entries above are from the computer that is not working. So the SQL Server on the non-working machine has an available instance.*

[image]

For the computer that is NOT showing any SQL Servers I have tried the following with no success:

- Upgraded the OS from Windows 10 to Windows 11
- Followed the directions from Microsoft to open ports TCP 1433 and UDP 1434
- Made sure the option to hide my SQL server instance is not enabled
- Reinstalled ODBC drivers
- Checked permissions

Nothing is working. Even my other computer can see my SQL Server instance, but I can't. I can type the server instance manually and that works. But I am dying to figure this out! This makes no sense to me. Also, the computer that works takes almost no time to build the list. On the computer that it's not working, it sits there for a long time before coming back empty.

I thought this could be a permission issue with my account, but it works fine on my other computer using the same account. The only other thing I can think of is it might be a policy issue, but I'm not sure where to go or look for a policy that might affect it. These are both work computers on a domain and even support here can't figure it out.

Any help/direction is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is just a stab, but maybe try disconnecting the machine from the domain and reconnecting, or recreating the AD machine account.  Verify the PC's secure channel.

Comment: Did you verify that the SQL Browser service is running?

Comment: @GeorgeMastros I have verified the Browser service is running. My SQL Instance does show on the other working notebook.

Comment: @squillman I'm on work computers, so I have no access to disconnect from the domain or create the AD on this machine again. I could put a support request to rebuild the AD, but not sure if they would do it.

Comment: Right, understood.  If SQL Server is the only thing giving you issues they might balk at it but it's something to try.  I used to see _all kinds_ of funky problems like this due to AD issues when I was doing network admin.

Comment: @squillman Thanks for the feedback. I'll see if support will rebuild the AD, but they have pretty much already washed their hands of my issue.

Comment: Slight detour...you need to think about upgrading from sql server 2012. It's end of life is about a month away.

Comment: In your question you said "switch" but then in the comments you said "notebook". Are these computers connected to said switch using ethernet cables, or are they using Wi-Fi? Most Wi-Fi access points have some kind of "Wi-Fi Access Point Isolation" configuration that prevents the connected devices from communicating with each other, only being able to communicate with upstream devices connected via the LAN/WAN port. It seems something like that could be enabled for one of your notebooks.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I had thought of that issue too, so I've tried both Wi-Fi and cable connections. At the moment, they are both connected to the same switch via cables.

Comment: @SeanLange The SQL Server 2012 is the drive that ships with Windows. I'm actually using SQL Server 2019 on both my notebooks and the driver is working fine on both, I'm just not able to get the list of available servers from the one notebook. I can manually enter a server instance and it works, but I'm trying to figure out why the server list doesn't get populated on the one notebook.

Comment: To everyone one that posted a response, it's looking like this could be a DNS issue based on Wireshark scans sent to IT. When I get back into the office and have access to the notebook again I'm going to update the DNS on the broken notebook to see if that fixes the issue. If it does, I will post an Answer to the question below for others to benefit from.